# Convert HH:MM:SS.mm to seconds in bash

Tags: bash

I am running some gnu time scripts which generates output of the form
mm:ss.mm (minutes, seconds and miliseconds, for example 1:20.66)
or hh:MM:ss (hours, minutes and seconds, for example 1:43:38).
I want to convert this to seconds (in order to compare them and plot them in a graphic).

Which is the easiest way to do this using bash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you can run the GNU `date` command:

```
date +'%s' -d "01:43:38.123"
```

If the script is generating "mm:ss.mm" you'll need to add "00:" to the beginning, or `date` will reject it.

If you're on a BSD system (including Mac OS X), you need to run `date -j +'%s' "0143.38"` unless you have GNU date installed with MacPorts or [Homebrew](http://braumeister.org/formula/coreutils) or something.

Comment: Just a note that date will run issues if you're trying to interpret standards like those seen in [GTFS](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference?hl=en#stop_timestxt), where time can go beyond 23 hours. E.g., 27:05:00 is legitimate.

Comment: (at least on my WSL ubuntu) I had to add 1970 and UTC in order to get number of seconds, otherwise `date` assumed that HH:MM:SS was "today". Example with `dur=00:00:24.60`: 
`date +'%s' -d "$dur"` #output something like `1588161624` / 
`date +'%s' -d "01/01/1970 $dur UTC"` #output `24` (note it does drop the decimals)

Answer (score 12):

```
$ TZ=utc date -d '1970-01-01 1:43:38' +%s
6218
```

Comment: Or put the timezone in the date string: “date -d '1970-01-01 1:43:38Z' +%s”

Answer (score 7):

And if you want pure Bash you can do something like

```
IFS=: read h m s <<<"${hms%.*}"
seconds=$((10#$s+10#$m*60+10#$h*3600))
```

The `10#` part is mandatory to specify that the numbers are given in radix 10. Without this, you'd get errors if `h`, `m` or `s` is `08` or `09` (as Bash interprets numbers with a leading `0` in octal).