# Asterisk: How to convert time to seconds

Tags: bash, shell, time, asterisk, duration

I want print only any result when $9 is greather than one hour
how can i convert this to seconds?
so i can use 3600sec for the check.

$9 = duration of a call 00:00:00

`asterisk -rx "core show channels verbose" | awk '$9 > "01:00:00"' | awk '$6 == "Dial"' | wc -l > test.txt`

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178032/convert-hhmmss-mm-to-seconds-in-bash

Comment: Better to post the final goal here, since you are using way too many pipes. What is the output of `asterisk -rx...`? What is the expected output?

Comment: Why can't you just check whether the first two numbers of the time are `0`, otherwise it's atleast one hour ?

Comment: @m0le121- have you solved your problem? If you have and StackOverflow helped, you should mark an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone mentioned, the easiest thing is to check if the first two digits of the time are not "00". Like this:

```
asterisk -rx "core show channels verbose" | awk '$9 !~ /00:..:../ && $6 == "Dial"' | wc -l
```

That means that it will match and record "01:00:00" which may not be what you want :-( . It matches "$9 greater than or equal to one hour".

This would match your "greater than" condition:

```
asterisk -rx "core show channels verbose" | awk '$9 !~ /00:..:../ && $9 != "01:00:00" && $6 == "Dial"' | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply extract `hour` `minute` and `sec` from the format `hh:mm:ss`, like this:

```
h=$(echo "$9" | cut -d":" -f1)
m=$(echo "$9" | cut -d":" -f2)
s=$(echo "$9" | cut -d":" -f3)
```

As you already have the `h` `m` and `s` values at hand now, you can convert it to seconds like this:

```
totalsec=$(echo "$h*3600+$m*60+$s"|bc)
```

or use `$h` if you need to check only for hours.